# Effective Hamiltonian for twisted bilayer graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, graphene

I'm trying to follow along with [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01556), which reviews the Bistrizer--MacDonald model of twisted bilayer graphene. I'm particular, I'm struggling to derive their Eq. (100). Starting from the Hamiltonian for both layers [Eq. (99)], the authors claim they can "integrate out states from layer 2" to obtain an effective Hamiltonian for layer 1. This is supposed to result in Eq. (100).

I'm unsure what the process of "integrating out" states actually means. I have seen mention of "downfolding" methods for obtaining effective Hamiltonians - if this is how the authors are proceeding, could someone suggest how Eq. (100) comes out of Eq. (99)? I would be most appreciative if you could let me know.

Comment: Are you familiar with the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics / QFT? It is by no means necessary to understand what the authors mean by "integrate out", but imo it is more intuitive in that language.

Comment: @NandagopalManoj I’m learning it now, but I’m not familiar enough with it yet to go making any serious computations. Could you explain to me what the authors mean by “integrate out” at a more pedestrian level?